# Not accepting regex in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, regex

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9'!@#%$^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};:"\\|,.<>\/? ]*$/
```

This regex is not working correctly in IOS. It is not accepting `'` character.
Please help

```js
let text = "String with a '";

var letters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9'!@#%$^&*()_+\-=[]{};:"\\|,.<>\/? ]*$/;
if (!(text.match(letters))) {
  console.log("No Special Characters Allowed");
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://regex101.com/r/LdbNdV/1

Comment: Please can you post the whole test string?  (Or is it literally just the ' character?).  Is it possible it is a backtick instead? (i.e. `)

Comment: Or [any of the many other character that looks like an apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Unicode).

Comment: var letters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9'!@#%$^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};:"\\|,.<>\/? ]*$/;
  if (!(text.match(letters))) {
        //alert("No Special Characters Allowed");
        return false;}
In Iphone it is not accepting apostrophe(')

Comment: @Afshan The regex you use in your code is not the same as you pasted in your question. If I use the one you used in your question it works fine.

Comment: It looks like one of the questions before. The `'` is automatically turned into a curly quote `’`. Try adding it to the regex, probably, together with `‘`. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9'‘’!@#%$^&*()_+=\[]{};:"\\|,.<>\/? -]*$/`. Or, turn that feature off using `input.smartQuotesType = .no` (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/2865931-smartquotestype))